# Laravel sqlite3 Eloquent searching database table for specific keyword

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite

How would I go about searching my database using a keyword that was inputted by the user, and then displaying the most relevant results on another page?
The code I supplied down below just gives my a blank page, I first assumed this was simply because I had nothing in my database but when I checked there was an input with that keyword.

My search function:

```
public function searchUsers()
{
    $searchWord = Input::get('searchBox');

    return View::make('user.search')->with('users', User::where('fullname', 'LIKE', '%'. $searchWord .'%'));
}
```

The user inputs the word in this blade form:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => secure_url('user/searchUsers'), 'class'=>'form-group has-feedback')) }}
<h1 style="font-size:55px; text-align:center;">Search for Friendship!</h1>
<br>
{{ Form::text('searchBox', $value = null, array('placeholder' => 'Search', 'class'=> 'form-control input-lg','autofocus' => 'autofocus')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

How I display my results:

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
      <div id="commentPanel"class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">{{ $user->fullname }}</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <p id="commentP">{{ $user->email }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are not returning the users from database, you just set where condition to the Eloquent object which simply returns a query object. Change your return statement to be like this:

```
return View::make('user.search')
       ->with(
          'users',
           User::where('fullname', 'LIKE', '%'. $searchWord .'%')->get()
       );
```